# Ruby string size in MB

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, size

This is probably a simple question. However I am simply wondering how to I create a string or array in ruby so that I know that it is 1MB large. Or any size for that matter.

Comment: 1M character bytes (`"a" * 10**6`) or actually used memory?

Comment: Lets say i want to send data as a string message to a server to do some testing.
I want to be able to send data of 1 MB and 10MB size.
So one character is 1 byte?

Comment: No, there is no guarantee that one character is one byte. Ruby Implementations are free to implement strings however they wish. Note also that for strings encoded in, say, UTF-32 or UTF-16, character will typically be *larger* than a byte.

Comment: Hm ok, however, "ok".bytesize => 2
So this means that it is still not 2 bytes?

Answer (score 2):

To create a million-character string:

```
"a" * 10**6
```

If you want it to read well and are using Rails or don't mind requiring `active_support/core_ext` then you can do the following:

```
"a" * 1.megabyte
"a" * 10.megabytes
```

This uses the traditional definition of megabyte (power of 2 instead of 10).

Note that this is assuming you're sending ASCII characters to a service, not trying to estimate how Ruby stores them.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. The Ruby Language Specification only specifies the *behavior* of strings, not how they are stored. It is perfectly legal, for example, for an implementation to compress strings (in which case the size of the string in memory will be smaller than you think), to de-duplicate them (in which case the size will be 0). Rubinius, for example, stores strings as *ropes*, as far as I know, which means that parts of strings may be shared with parts of other strings, so the notion of "size" isn't even well-defined in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size of the internal String buffer these days with the `capacity:` keyword argument. It's great if you know the size of a String up front, since you'll then not need reallocs as you shovel on repeatedly.

```
String.new(capacity: 10**6)
```